# Normalize Sound from other people in webex?

Tags: windows-10, webex, cisco-webex

Is it possible to normalize the sound coming from all people in a webex meeting? Some people I need to hear in my meetings are really soft while others are too loud. Is there any way to make everyone the same volume or to turn down the volume on the extra loud people?

Comment: What OS? Mac, Win, nix?

Comment: @Tetsujin Added windows-10 tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was requested in the feature request
[Add ability to adjust participants volume or normalize volume while in a meeting](https://ciscocollabcustomer.ideas.aha.io/ideas/WXCUST-I-1139)
from Sep 24 2020, but didn't get (yet?) an answer from Webex.

I don't know if it will help for Webex, but for video play in Windows
you could turn on Loudness Equalization:

- Open *Control Panel > Sound* and position to the Playback tab
- Click your sound device
- Click the Properties button
- In the Properties dialog, go to the Enhancements tab
- Place a check-mark next to Loudness Equalization
- Click OK.